# как дождаться выполнение js(ajax) скрипта selenium?

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

На сайте изменяется viewbox у svg после полной загрузки страницы.
Не могу понять в чем дело, уже чего не пробовал только от sleep до ожидание изменений viewbox.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-automation')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    for key, value in headers.items():
        chrome_options.add_argument(f'--{key}={value}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=sel_options)



driver.get(url)

cookie = {

}

driver.add_cookie(cookie)

driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

 initial_viewbox = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('figure 
 svg').getAttribute('viewBox')")


 wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "figure svg[value='" + initial_viewbox + "']")))
```

это один из последних проб получить измененный viewbox...